# How to READ_SMS works in ionic3?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with ionic 3 and I want to use a plugin which will read SMS automatically like auto read. I'm able to get SMS and allow all the permissions. But autoread SMS is not happening.
Is there any configuration which I'm missing.

Comment: Do you mean by the OTP auto fill like that.

Comment: @Sathiyaraj Yes, I want this only, but now it is working. Actually in new ionic sms plugin READ_SMS function is not there, I i've installed previous sms plugin and not it is reading automatically. Thanks !!!

Comment: Which plugin your using right now.

Comment: @Sathiyaraj Previously I was using cordova-sms-plugin which is only for sending SMS it is not responsible for receive or read SMS. But now I'm using cordova-plugin-sms@1.0.5 which is only for android and its working for both send and read SMS.